# Why can't this executable find this shared library?

Tags: c++, linker, shared-libraries, conan

I am compiling an executable on linux through conan, meson and gcc. I am inspecting the final binary:

```
 readelf -d uproject | head -20
Dynamic section at offset 0xd4b00 contains 36 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libne_core.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libne_loader.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libcamera.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgeometry.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libimage.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/makogan/.conan/data/NeverEngine/0.0.1/_/_/package/fd44bedc483c60110edc71130be63a73237c36f4/lib]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x70000
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0xab9e4
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0xd59a8
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       16 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0xd59b8
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x3b0
```

I then verify the runpath:

```
 ls /home/makogan/.conan/data/NeverEngine/0.0.1/_/_/package/fd44bedc483c60110edc71130be63a73237c36f4/lib
Animation.cpp.o                    HalfEdge_HMesh.cpp.o           libgeometry.so            libNeverEngine.so         Log.cpp.o                          Swapchain.cpp.o
AnimationMesh.cpp.o                HalfEdge_HMeshInternals.cpp.o  libgeometry.so.symbols    libprofiler.so            ModuleStorage.cpp.o                tracy_TracyClient.cpp.o
CacheUtils.cpp.o                   HalfEdge_Subdivision.cpp.o     libimage.so               libprofiler.so.symbols    NumericIntegration.cpp.o           Utils.cpp.o
Camera.cpp.o                       HardwareInterface.cpp.o        libimage.so.symbols       libspirv_cross_c.a        Parametrics_Parametrics.cpp.o      VkExtensionsStubs.cpp.o
CLI.cpp.o                          imgui_bridge.cpp.o             libimgui.so               libspirv_cross_core.a     Peripherals.cpp.o                  VulkanDebugging.cpp.o
Core.cpp.o                         _imgui.cpp.o                   libmisc_utils.so          libspirv_cross_cpp.a      Pipeline.cpp.o                     VulkanImage.cpp.o
CpuImage.cpp.o                     InputHandler.cpp.o             libmisc_utils.so.symbols  libspirv_cross_glsl.a     pkgconfig                          VulkanMemory.cpp.o
Gallery.cpp.o                      libanimation.so                libne_core.so             libspirv_cross_hlsl.a     profiler.cpp.o                     Window.cpp.o
GeometryUtils_GeometryUtils.cpp.o  libanimation.so.symbols        libne_core.so.symbols     libspirv_cross_msl.a      Renderer.cpp.o
GLFW_tools.cpp.o                   libcamera.so                   libne_loader.so           libspirv_cross_reflect.a  Scribe.cpp.o
GlslParsing.cpp.o                  libcamera.so.symbols           libne_loader.so.symbols   libspirv_cross_util.a     ShaderProgram.cpp.o
GltfLib.cpp.o                      libfilesystem.so               libne_peripherals.so      libui_utils.so            ShapeAnalysis_HeatGeodesics.cpp.o
GltfLoaders.cpp.o                  libfilesystem.so.symbols       libne_renderer.so         libui_utils.so.symbols    SpringMass.cpp.o
```

However when I run the program I get:

`./uproject: error while loading shared libraries: libprofiler.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Why? the files are clearly and exactly on the specified path. I see `libprofiler.so` among the files in the runpath directory.

Output with ldd:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff4a6ff000)
        libne_core.so => /home/makogan/.conan/data/NeverEngine/0.0.1/_/_/package/fd44bedc483c60110edc71130be63a73237c36f4/lib/libne_core.so (0x00007f75f8a9c000)
        libne_loader.so => /home/makogan/.conan/data/NeverEngine/0.0.1/_/_/package/fd44bedc483c60110edc71130be63a73237c36f4/lib/libne_loader.so (0x00007f75f8a55000)
        libcamera.so => /home/makogan/.conan/data/NeverEngine/0.0.1/_/_/package/fd44bedc483c60110edc71130be63a73237c36f4/lib/libcamera.so (0x00007f75f896d000)
        libgeometry.so => /home/makogan/.conan/data/NeverEngine/0.0.1/_/_/package/fd44bedc483c60110edc71130be63a73237c36f4/lib/libgeometry.so (0x00007f75f84a5000)
        libimage.so => /home/makogan/.conan/data/NeverEngine/0.0.1/_/_/package/fd44bedc483c60110edc71130be63a73237c36f4/lib/libimage.so (0x00007f75f846e000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f75f823e000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f75f815a000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f75f8140000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f75f7f18000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f75f8c41000)
        libprofiler.so => not found
        libfilesystem.so => not found
```

Dump of libne_renderer.so:

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x68f750 contains 35 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libne_core.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libprofiler.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libfilesystem.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libX11.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libshaderc_shared.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libvulkan.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libne_renderer.so]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [$ORIGIN/../Core:$ORIGIN/../Profiler:$ORIGIN/../../Tools/FileSystem]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x2a7000
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x586f1c
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x68ec30
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       40 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x68ec58
```

And the ldd:

```
ldd lib/libne_renderer.so 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffddfbed000)
        libne_core.so => not found
        libprofiler.so => not found
        libfilesystem.so => not found
        libX11.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f362ca25000)
        libshaderc_shared.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libshaderc_shared.so.1 (0x00007f362c2de000)
        libvulkan.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1 (0x00007f362c26f000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f362c056000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f362bf72000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f362bf58000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f362bd30000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f362bd06000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f362bcff000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f362bcfa000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f362d24d000)
        libXau.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f362bcf4000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f362bcec000)
        libbsd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0 (0x00007f362bcd4000)
        libmd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd.so.0 (0x00007f362bcc5000)
```

Comment: what happens if you run ```ldd uproject```?

Comment: seems to not find 2 of the shared libraries, but don;t know why, they are both on the directory @ewong

Comment: but is are those libs in paths in the ld.so.conf?  (iirc)

Comment: check that these files are indeed shared libraries and that they have appropriate permissions.

Comment: The two libraries are not in the list of libraries in the elf dynamic section that you included. I suspect that they are used by any of the other libraries, which not have the rpath set correctly. Could you try `ldd libne_core.so`, `ldd libne_loader.se` ,... and see which one of them uses `libprofiler.so` and/or `libfilesystem.so`.

Comment: There's a few, one such file is the renderer one, i.e. libne_renderer.so

Comment: @JakobStark I added the outputs for one of the binaries (I fear doing all of them would make this post really long)

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I think, when a dynamic library is linked (during runtime) the dynamic linker tries to resolve the dependencies recursively. But for example for `libne_renderer.so`'s dependencies, only the rpath of that library is considered, not the original onn of the application. Thus it fails finding the right path.

Comment: Is that `NeverEngine` conan package a custom built package?

Comment: It's my packege (i.e. I am the author) but it was installed in the system by conan. @JakobStark

Comment: @Makogan Unfortunately I don't know the standard way of handling shared libraries in conan. But maybe [this](https://docs.conan.io/en/1.43/howtos/manage_shared_libraries.html) helps.

Comment: Look at the runpath of libne_renderer.so. It looks like it expects to find each library (or a set of libraries) in its own subdirectory, presumably libne_core.so in Core/libne_core.so and libprofiler.so in Profiler/libprofiler.so etc, but instead all the libraries are lumped flat in one directory. It seems the configuration of the executable and the configuration of the libraries are not talking to each other.

Comment: I think it is rather a problem in the interaction between the configuration of the library and the conan packaging procedure. The RPATH of the shared libraries should probably just be `$ORIGIN` and not `$ORIGIN/../Core:$ORIGIN/../Profiler:$ORIGIN/../../Tools/FileSystem`.

Comment: @Makogan Maybe changing `keep_path` to `True` in [this](https://gitlab.com/Makogan/ne2/-/blob/master/conanfile.py#L125) line helps, because it reflects the directory structure of the build into the package layout.